# Save Path of AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am playing around with the `AVAudioRecorder` so I can have it in my app.

I am using the following code from a tutorial.

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
```

everything goes fine.

But I have a question regarding of the savedPath of `AVAudioRecorder`.

I know this will save to the application's document folder, but can it be saved to somewhere, so the Music app can play it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path has to point somewhere within your application bundle. Because apps are sandboxed, you won't be able to record to a place accessible in the Music app. As far as I know, apps are not allowed to add recordings directly to the Music library, but I could be wrong on this.

You should probably save to your app's Documents directory. If don't want the recording to be backed up to iCloud automatically, you could consider saving to a subdirectory of your app's Library directory instead.